# Impossible to log in to Backoffice in PrestaShop 1.7.2.0

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

**Error description:** nothing is shown when trying to log in.

We enter user (mail) and password, it tries to log in but nothing happens.
Inspecting browser’s console but no error is shown, nor even a clue to follow.

**Additional information:**

- PrestaShop version: 1.7.2
- PHP version: 7.1.33
- Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73

**We've tried this:**

- Empty the cache and cookies
- Verified PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL on ps_contiguration table
- Cache manual deletion on app/cache/dev and app/cache/prod
- Deactivation of IP check at clases/Cookie.php commenting the condition:

  (!isset($this->_content['remote_addr']) || $this->_content['remote_addr'] == ip2long(Tools::getRemoteAddr()) || !Configuration::get('PS_COOKIE_CHECKIP’))

In the route /PROJECT_FOLDER/classes/controller/AdminController.php

**we’ve replaced this:**

```
if ($this->context->cookie->last_activity + 900 < time()) {
```

**by this:**

```
if ($this->context->cookie->last_activity + 3600 < time()) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVING.**

The error was an admin login loop. it was a server error due to excess ajax requests

I leave the solution in case someone else has the same problem:

In ps_configuration table disable PS_COOKIE_CHECKIP

**before:**

PS_COOKIE_CHECKIP = 1

**then:**

PS_COOKIE_CHECKIP = 0

Comment: This is enabled for security reasons; if I were you I'll look further to find the cause that leads to so many blocking ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the errors when no BO access, go by SFTP/FTP to config/defines.inc.php and change the `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false)` to `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true)` then you'll be able to proceed and investigate accordingly.